# RP-467 Senior Tax Exemption, do you need to submit your tax returns?

Tags: united-states, taxes, new-york, property-taxes

I am trying to file a form RP-467 for the Senior Citizen tax exemption for a family member. The instructions say that the deadline is March 1st, and that you need to include your tax returns.  The tax forms don't come in until Feb 15th, do they really expect you to get your taxes together and file in 2 weeks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the complexity of the return, it is sometimes possible to file before March 1st.

Anyway, the [instructions](https://www.tax.ny.gov/pdf/current_forms/orpts/rp467ins.pdf) (pdf) for line 13 of the RP-467 form state:

> You can still file your application for exemption with your assessor
>   pending any submission of income tax return(s) you are required to
>   provide with Form RP-467 or RP-467-RNW.